# Derive sha1 hash from openssl binary base64 value

Tags: openssl, checksum, base64, sha1

Digital Cinema Packages contain checksums in the following format as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Cinema_Package#Asset_map_file):

```
$ openssl sha1  -binary 'dcpfile.xml' |openssl base64
IxcfhXNHlw+1bbDFu0kp8KRylpU=
```

How can I take a value such as `IxcfhXNHlw+1bbDFu0kp8KRylpU=` and derive the original sha1 hash, which would look something like

```
$ openssl sha1 'dcpfile.xml' 
SHA1(dcpfile.xml)= 23171f857347970fb56db0c5bb4929f0a4729695
```

My use case is that there are not many checksum validation tools that exist that easily allow you to validate an md5sum type checksum manifest that use these binary/base64 values, but there are many tools that validate sha1, so it would be great if I knew how to reverse these values so I could write a script that would generate a more interoperable list of hashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both values are **the same hash** – the same "binary" bytes shown in two different encodings (representations), and neither is more "original" than the other.

(Base64 has 6 bits per character; hexadecimal aka base-16 has 4 bits per digit. Three raw bytes, four Base64 digits, six hex digits are directly convertible.)

Just about every programming language will have functions to encode/decode these formats. For example, in shell tools:

- To decode Base64 into raw binary data, use `base64 -d` or `openssl base64 -d`.
- To encode raw binary data into hexadecimal, use `xxd -p` or `hexdump`.

```
$ echo 23171f857347970fb56db0c5bb4929f0a4729695 | xxd -r -p | base64
IxcfhXNHlw+1bbDFu0kp8KRylpU=

$ echo IxcfhXNHlw+1bbDFu0kp8KRylpU= | base64 -d | hd
00000000  23 17 1f 85 73 47 97 0f  b5 6d b0 c5 bb 49 29 f0  |#...sG...m...I).|
00000010  a4 72 96 95                                       |.r..|
```

Comment: Perfect, so this    `openssl sha1  -binary 'dcp_file.xml' |openssl base64 | base64 -d | xxd -p`  will produce 
`23171f857347970fb56db0c5bb4929f0a4729695` - now I just need to do it all in python which I think you have told me how to figure out. Thank you!

Comment: Import `base64` and `binascii`.

Comment: Thank you!! This will make my life so much easier.

Comment: ```import binascii

import base64

a = 'IxcfhXNHlw+1bbDFu0kp8KRylpU='

b = base64.b64decode(a)

binascii.hexlify(b).decode()

u'23171f857347970fb56db0c5bb4929f0a4729695'```